# How to properly run a mouse-imitating macro with the Input of a controller?

Tags: python, linux, mouseevent, xbox, autokey

I've searched through many internet forums to find pretty much nothing, that can solve my problem:

I'm a former user of the scripting Language AutoHotKey, so as I'm also using Linux, I want to properly imitate the same code I have in AutoHotKey to run on Linux.

What I've found:

- PyMouse (too complicated, as im not a python programmer)
- xdotool (not at all responding to hotkeys, but producing results wanted)
- AutoKey (not recognizing xbox360 Controller input and the input between mouse clicked and mouse released, cannot be controlled)

Is there any way of kinda replicating the following "verbal-code" into something more useable to act on Linux?

```
XBOX Controller Input: C-Button left/right/up or down whatever
Mouse-Move to 1920/2 1080/2
Mouse-Click-Down 
Mouse-Move to 1920/2+50 1080/2+50
Sleep 500 ms
Mouse-Click-Up
Send-Key ESC
return
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xboxdrv.1.html?

Comment: I do have xboxdrv installed
As I'm new to the scene, I'd maybe need some assistance in this case ^^, if it can make xdotool run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The Thing is, Linux works very weird with XBOX Controllers*, so to accomplish a simple Mouseclick, you need to rethink and combine multiple Tools, to do so...

### How it works:

- Download Antimicro
- Download xdotool

Create a Script file for xdotool on kate or nano or whatever writing program you use.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool mousemove 1890, 990
xdotool mousedown 1
xdotool sleep 0.05
xdotool mouseup 1
```

Save the file and go to properties, mark as 'Executeable'

Go-To custom Shortcuts for your System. How its called is different from your OS type.
Assign the file you just created to a hotkey X (note, controllerinput wont work)

Start antimicro and assign the controller Key to the Hotkey X

Finito. Though it is very painful to set it up.

This way you can for any instance, simulate mouse macro movement for controllers e.g. you can now emulate better touch related games like The Legend Of Zelda on the nintendo 3Ds.

Comment: Anyone know a better solution?

Comment: When setting up conditions on the custom Shortcuts, you can specify the Movement by selecting an active Window or other different parameters to keep the Shortcuts alive and not turn them on repeadedly. This way it's actually quite nice to use.
Starting up Antimicro still annoys me.